Multiple distributions from single Python repository
I'm looking for a way to create multiple distribution package configurations from a single repository. For example, given my source layout:
project/
|__src/
|  |__a/
|  |  |__a.py
|  |  b/
|  |  |__b.py
|  |  c/
|  |  |__c.py
|__pyproject.toml

I want two create two different flavors of distribution packages:
project_a+b+c-v0.0.1     # for internal use; everything included
project_c_only-v0.0.1    # for external use; package "c" only

Is there an existing pattern for this kind of thing using pyproject.toml?

As far as I know, there are no standard pyproject.toml fields that would allow you to do this directly. A workaround might be to clone the repository, remove all unnecessary things and build as normal.

You could configure two packages with different setups, both of which would include the shared code. Another approach would be to use 'extras' in your package setup. The first setup allows you to create a package that will only contain the shared code, with no option to install the rest, the second allows you to keep everything within a single package with the option to install the extras (e.g. pip install mypackage[some_extra])

Make project_c a separate package and declare it as a required dependency in project_a+b+c.
